# Regression models to only predict integers (instead of floating point numbers)?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, count-data

I have a dataset that consists of about 50 different attributes. One of these attributes I want to predict, using the other attributes as features. The values of the attribute that I want to predict are always non-negative integers. Most often they are in the range between 0 and 5, but sometimes they can reach a value of around 100.

I thought that using regression would be the optimal solution here, but I have also seen that regression models often can be limited to only predict integers. Instead they predict any floating point number.

So my question is: Is a regression model the right way to go for my data and if yes, Is there any approach that let me limit the prediction range?

Comment: It seems to me your data have *all* the characteristics you mention: integers certainly are numeric; they can be ordered (making them ordinal), and they can be used as discrete attributes (making them nominal). Instead of a having a problem, it would seem you have the opposite: you could use practically any method you think might work. Why, then, are you stuck?

Comment: The problem is that when I use weka to predict numeric values using regression, it predicts floating point numbers, because it assume that numeric attributes are always floating point numbers (http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/index.html?weka/classifiers/functions/package-tree.html). That makes my prediction less accurate than possible, since the classifier never predicts the actual value, since it always tries to predict a floating point number. I think if I could add a constrain to the classifier, saying that the result can only by integers, it would be way more accurate.

Comment: You might find it more fruitful to think about your question generally and forget about Weka for awhile. That would cause you to focus on the nature of the data--what they mean, how they are related, how they can vary--and on the particulars of your problem--whether it is prediction or estimation or whatever. That will open up the possibilities and allow readers to make suggestions focused on what you truly need.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I reformulated my question completely. I hope it helps.

Comment: Methods to perform a regression where the outcome is non-negative integers include binomial, Poisson, negative binomial regression. There are a number of questions on these topics on this website.

Comment: Depending on how your integers arise you might use say GLMs for counts or ordered-categorical methods (for ordinal categories); in some cases (especially if your integers stay away from very small values (0,1,...) and don't cover too wide a range) simply rounding results from a linear regression may be feasible. More information would be necessary to give a detailed answer -- how do these integers arise? What are they?

Comment: You might even try rounding to the nearest valid integer.